# How can I inject props to a child component without having to use the Consumer component?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

How can I inject props from a Context consumer directly, without having to use the Consumer component? I would love to do it like the Formik example below but really not sure how I can achieve that. Any help is much appreciated.

```
// my example
<DropDown>
  <DropDown.Toggle>
    <button>Test</button>
  </DropDown.Toggle>

  <DropDownContext.Consumer>
    {({ isOpen, toggle }) => (
      <>
        <DropDown.Contents>
          <div className={isOpen ? "bg-green" : "bg-red"}></div>
        </DropDown.Contents>
      </>
    )}
  </DropDownContext.Consumer>
</DropDown>;

// what i want
<Formik
  initialValues={{ name: "jared" }}
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }}
>
  {/* I don't want to have to use Context.Consumer */}
  {(props) => (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        onBlur={props.handleBlur}
        value={props.values.name}
        name="name"
      />
      {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

Comment: if you're using hooks, you can use React.useContext

Comment: yes that's absolutely right, but in this case I do not want to use hooks, I just want to style certain children differently but want to define those in the parent dropdown